# Were elderly patients denied dialysis in the UK during the 70s?

Tags: united-kingdom, healthcare

During a news broadcast by the Israeli public channel on March 15<sup>th</sup>, [prof. Jonathan Halevy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Halevy), the manager of the [Shaare Zedek Medical Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaare_Zedek_Medical_Center) said:

> לבריטניה יש היסטוריה עם בעניין הזה. בשנות ה-70 לא עשו דיאליזה באנגליה לחולים מעל גיל 70

> Britain has a history with this issue. During the 70s patients above the age of 70 did not receive dialysis in England

This was said with regards to the British suggested policy of quarantining only the elderly and people with increased risk factors to die from COVID-19 and allow the rest of the "healthy" population to be infected by the virus.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duVG9BJecp8) at 21:50.

Comment: I can't address the specifics but in the early days there weren't enough dialysis machines and hospitals had to decide who gets to live and who dies.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, if you have a source, it would be great, what would make it better is a comparison to other countries at that time and see how they reacted to the same problems, as this is the main theme of the argument, that Britain is willing to sacrifice its elderly, while other countries make an effort to protect them.

Comment: I wasn't specifically referring to England, but rather the early days of dialysis.  It's not like the factories could magically produce enough machines for everyone at once.